# Top box shadow not visible

Tags: html, css

When I use Overflow hidden on my row the box shadow at the top and bottom is hidden how can I fix this

Box shadow on the top and bottom is not visible or cut out because I added css style to my row and set properties to overflow hidden and cuts out the box shadow from the top and bottom

Comment: Do a minimal reproduction : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you could add padding equal to the size of your box shadow if you need the overflow hidden

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.